# mysql insert Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql

```
$count = count(array_filter($_POST["materials"]));  
for($I = 0; $I < $count; $i++)  
{ 
    $insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO table1 (uid, materials, num, cost)
            VALUES
            (
            '$_POST[uid]',
            '$_POST[material][$i]',
            '$_POST[num][$i]',
            '$_POST[cost][$i]',
            )");        
}
```

If I use `echo $_post[materials][$i]` it's giving me right result but in database it is inserting something like `array[0]`.

Seems my `$insert` is not right. But I don't have any idea to insert it. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: `echo` your query to see the exact raw mysql query with variables substituted.

Comment: what does your form look like

Comment: there are 3 forms materials, num, cost. each of them multiplied 5 times.

Comment: One advice (may be you're following it): **Please sanitize and validate your input before inserting into the database**.

Comment: Try changing `$_POST[material][$i]` to `$_POST['materials'][$i]`

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can (and have to) use a pair of curly braces around the expressions, and also quote the array keys:

```
$insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO table1 (uid, materials, num, cost)
            VALUES
            (
            '{$_POST['uid']}',
            '{$_POST['material'][$i]}',
            '{$_POST['num'][$i]}',
            '{$_POST['cost'][$i]}',
            )");
```

See [php.net > Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

It's because PHP's variable parsing in strings is limited to single-dimension array. For two or more dimensions you need to use the curly braces to indicate PHP the end of the variable. Same applies to accessing arrays with a string key.

You also need to quote the string array keys because they are actual strings, which you should *always* quote them properly

---

Also note that the code is fine if it is not production code. However you should be aware that your code opens a big security vulnerability called [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). If this is more serious work, you should refer to the link and fix the security vulnerability.

Comment: if i use curly braces i got another notice `Notice: Use of undefined constant`

Comment: @moogiienhtsogt there was another error in your original code. Pointed it out in the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Array to string: [implode(',', $_POST[material][$i])](http://hk.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: where should i put it? sorry im new in php

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_template = "INSERT INTO table1 (uid, materials, num, cost)
        VALUES(%d, %s, %s, %s)")";

$insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO table1 (uid, materials, num, cost) = 
sprintf($sql_template, $_POST[uid], $_POST[material][$i], $_POST[num][$i], $_POST[cost][$i]);

mysqli_query($con,$insert);
```

For sprintf more details visit [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for data type and etc.